# Calling output from a string input from the first letter inputed

Tags: java, arrays, string, io

I'm trying to make a program that will have the use input there name then depending on the first letter of there first and last name so if there name was Bob Marley it would take B and get the output from the array letter1  then it would also take M and get the output from the array letter 2.

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Starwars

{
    static Map<String, String> firstNameMap;}firstNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        firstNameMap.put("A", "Cho");
    firstNameMap.put("B", "R2");
    firstNameMap.put("C", "C-3po");
    firstNameMap.put("D", "Yod");
    firstNameMap.put("E", "Nas");
    firstNameMap.put("F", "Slea");
    firstNameMap.put("G", "Jan");
    firstNameMap.put("H", "Zhur");
    firstNameMap.put("I", "Boba");
    firstNameMap.put("J", "Thre");
    firstNameMap.put("K", "Bib");
    firstNameMap.put("L", "Kit");
    firstNameMap.put("M", "Kyp");
    firstNameMap.put("N", "Gonk");
    firstNameMap.put("O", "Zlung");
    firstNameMap.put("P", "Adi");
    firstNameMap.put("Q", "Nat");
    firstNameMap.put("R", "Ru");
    firstNameMap.put("S", "Cla");
    firstNameMap.put("T", "Kir");
        firstNameMap.put("U", "Obi");
    firstNameMap.put("V", "Ken");
    firstNameMap.put("W", "Ziro");
    firstNameMap.put("X", "Zev");
    firstNameMap.put("Y", "Tavion");
    firstNameMap.put("Z", "Jar");

  public static void main ( String[] args )
  {
      String[] planet = null, rank = null, rebbelion = null, letter1 = null, letter2= null , Map , HashMap;
      String firstName, lastName ,name2 , side , location, fistNameMap;

     Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in ); //scanner initilized


    }

   /*  letter1 = new String[25];//Name generation array uses first letter of first name
    letter1 [0] = "Cho";
    letter1 [1] = "R2";
    letter1 [2] = "C-3po";
    letter1 [3] = "Yod";
    letter1 [4] = "Nas";
    letter1 [5] = "Slea";
    letter1 [6] = "Jan";
    letter1 [7] = "Zhur";
    letter1 [8] = "Boba";
    letter1 [9] = "Thre";
    letter1 [10] = "Bib";
    letter1 [11] = "Kit";
    letter1 [12] = "Kyp";
    letter1 [13] = "Gonk";
    letter1 [14] = "Zlung";
    letter1 [15] = "Adi";
    letter1 [16] = "Nat";
    letter1 [17] = "Ru";
    letter1 [18] = "Cla";
    letter1 [19] = "Kir";
    letter1 [20] = "Obi";
    letter1 [21] = "Ken";
    letter1 [22] = "Ziro";
    letter1 [23] = "Tion";
    letter1 [24] = "Zev";
    letter1 [25] = "Jar";
    letter1 [26] = "Tavion";


    letter2 = new String[27];//Name generation array2 uses first letter of the last name
    letter2 [0] = "tzki";
    letter2 [1] = "hut";
    letter2 [2] = "der";
    letter2 [3] = "kzos";
    letter2 [4] = "vos";
    letter2 [5] = "vader";
    letter2 [6] = "thrawn";
    letter2 [7] = "mesk";
    letter2 [8] = "thuo";
    letter2 [9] = "skywalker";
    letter2 [10] = "D2";
    letter2 [11] = "maul";
    letter2 [12] = "sith";
    letter2 [13] = "muzzar";
    letter2 [14] = "jusik";
    letter2 [15] = "horn";
    letter2 [16] = "phisto";
    letter2 [17] = "farlander";
    letter2 [18] = "dunhaussan";
    letter2 [19] = "jar";
    letter2 [20] = "binks";
    letter2 [21] = "lbis";
    letter2 [22] = "gnarzlo";
    letter2 [23] = "anakin";
    letter2 [24] = "ackbur";
    letter2 [25] = "axmis";
    letter2 [26] = "bacca";



    planet = new String[11]; //Planet options  

    planet[0] = "Alderaan";
    planet[1] = "Bespin";
    planet[2] = "Coruscant";
    planet[3]= "Forest moon of Endor";
    planet[4] = "Hoth";
    planet[5] = "Kamino";
    planet[6] = "Kashyyk";
    planet[7] = "Mustafar";
    planet[8] = "Yavin";
    planet[9] = "DEATH STAR";//Planet options  -END

    rank = new String[50]; //Diferent jobs or prefixes to the name
    rank[0] = "Clone";
    rank[1] = "Bounty Hunter";
    rank[2] = "Droid";
    rank[3]= "Jedi Knight";
    rank[4] = "Gungan";
    rank[5] = "Gangster";
    rank[6] = "commander";
    rank[7] = "Queen";
    rank[9] = "Empirer";
    rank[10] = "Darth";
    rank[11] = "captain";
    rank[12] = "ewok";
    */
                System.out.println("Welcome to the Star Wars name generator");
        System.out.println("What is your first name?");     //Name Generation
        String firstName = input.nextLine();                //Name Generation (i want to take the first letter of there input and get the output from letter1 matching that # ie c = letter1 [2]  a= letter1 [0])
        System.out.println("What is your last name?");      //Name Generation
        String lastName = input.nextLine();                 //Name Generation (i want to take the first letter of there input and get the output from letter2 matching that # ie c = letter2 [2]  a= letter2 [0])


    /*
    System.out.println("If you had to choose dark or light side?"); //Selection of Dark or Light side
    side = input1.nextString();                                     //Selection of Dark or Light side

        if (side = dark);
        {
            System.out.println("You Have chosen to be part of the dark side!");

        }


        else
        {
            System.out.println("You are now part of the light side!");

        } 
        */

    System.out.println("There are now several places you could live please choose one of the following by number:");    //Planet selections
    System.out.println("1) Alderaan 2) Bespin 3) Coruscant 4) Forest moon of Endor 5) Hoth ");                          //Planet selections
    System.out.println("6) Kamino 7) Kashyyk 8) Mustafar 9) Yavin 10)DEATHSTAR");                                       //Planet selections
    location = input1.nestString();



    //Final print out Statements
    System.out.println("You "/*instert name1 and name2 */" now fight for the "/*side they choose */" As a proud "/* Job/creature */"of the"+ location +"Good luck against your enemy's and may the force be with you");

  }
```

im getting errors for:

static Map firstNameMap;firstNameMap = new HashMap<>();  - cannot find symbol

firstNameMap.put("A", "Cho"); -  usage of static non final variable during initialization

Comment: So does 'B' correspond to "R2"?

Comment: @TNT Yes exactly that

Comment: And what letter or symbol would "Tavion" and "bacca" correspond to, then? They're the twenty-seventh elements of the array, yet there are only twenty-six letters in the alphabet.

Comment: @TNT That was an error we fixed earlier today new version of code with new problems was just uploaded...

Comment: The `static Map<String,String> firstNameMap = new HashMap<>();` and the `static` block where you add your `K` and `V` values should be outside the `main` method.

Comment: ok i did this ill post a new example in a moment now it says "class, interface, or enum expected" and my System.out.println still have errors

Comment: You have an extra } in your `Map` declaration line; remove it. Said line should look like this: `static Map<String,String> firstNameMap = new HashMap<String,String>();` Put the } immediately after `firstNameMap.put("Z", "Jar");`. Remove the } located after the `Scanner` initialization line. And in your final `System.out.println` statement, if there is no `+` present after an ending `"`, add one (except for the final `"`).

Comment: @TNT I have once again updated the post

Comment: Please read my comment again; there are some things that you did not do that will cause compilation errors.

Comment: I've edited my post so you can see the full picture. See if that helps.

Comment: I see an extra `}` after the `Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );` line in the `main()` method. Also, you're declaring some variables multiple times. You declare `firstName` and `lastName` as `String` in the first couple of lines of `main()`, but then you declare them again later in the method. You've also declared `Map` and `HashMap` as `String[]` in that first line, and `fistNameMap` (includes a spelling error) as a `String`, which you probably didn't mean to do.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd suggest using a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), mapping the first letter to names, instead of the arrays. Then, look up the name based on the first character of each inputted name. It would look something like

```
public class Starwars {
    private static Map<String, String> firstNameMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static {
        firstNameMap.put("A", "Cho");
        // etc.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Star Wars name generator");
        System.out.println("What is your first name?");   
        String firstName = input.nextLine();
        String newName = firstNameMap.get(firstName.toUpperCase().substring(0,1));

        System.out.println("What is your last name?");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();
        // Do something similar
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having multiple errors i will post details above in my post if you can help.

Comment: Updated the code so that you can see the structure of the class.

Answer (score 0):

juh's answer is correct, and includes the preferred method. However it is possible to do this by using arrays like you had earlier. By retrieving the first character from the input, you can subtract 'A' of 'a', depending on the casing, from the character to generate the corresponding index of the array. For example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is your first name?");
String firstName = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
System.out.println("What is your last name?");
String lastName = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();

String newFirstName = letter1[firstName.charAt(0) - 'A'];
String newLastName = letter2[lastName.charAt(0) - 'a'];
```

Make sure that you increase the size of your `letter1` array to avoid an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.